# Why is Planar algebras I (by Vaughan Jones) not published?

Tags: soft-question, oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, planar-algebras

On Saturday 4 September 1999, [Vaughan Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaughan_Jones) put on arXiv a paper entitled [*Planar algebras, I*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909027).

Until now, this preprint was cited 343 times (according to Google Scholar). It is often cited with the mention "to appear in New Zealand J. Math.", even nowadays after 20 years.

**Question**: Why is this paper not (yet) published? Is it still *under review* in New Zealand J. Math.? What are/were the requests of the referee? Who is/was the referee?

I would like to know the whole truth on this subject.

*Remark*: for people thinking that I just have to ask him, I want to say that I am not asking this question for myself only, I think that this information should be known to anyone interested in planar algebras from far or near. Moreover, I don't want to annoy him with a question that must have been asked to him too many times...

Comment: Just for context, Vaughan Jones passed away on September 6, 2020.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This paper is now published in New Zealand Journal of Mathematics Vol. 52 (2021).
https://doi.org/10.53733/172
[pdf file](https://nzjmath.org/index.php/NZJMATH/article/view/172/61)

Comment: The only trace in the paper of the recent work I could locate is the footnote p1 *"The editors thank Professor Martha “Wendy” Jones for agreeing to the publication of this paperwhich has been on arXiv at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909027 since 1999.The editors also thank Dr Tsukasa Yashiro for locating and making available his copy of the manuscript, especially of the figures."* They don't say (at least inside the pdf) if the paper has undergone any change beyond formatting, and whether it has been peer-reviewed.